# one example on game playing with some details, how this average step was calculated?

Tags: probability, computer-science

I have one example in my TA notes:

We have a `two players` games. two players will be agree on number $n$. game start with $x=2$. first player select by `Coin flipping` and start game. after that each of players arbitrary do one of the following: $x=x^2$ or $x=x^3$.

for example if "David" start game and choose $x^3$ then $x$ will be equals to $8$. after playing of each players that condition $x>n$ occurred, the game will be stopped and the last player announced as `winner`. at average this game ended after $O(\log \log n)$ steps.

This is very nice example, but how we can detect `this average order` can be achieved?

Comment: I've edited the tags: probability theory is for measure-theoretic study of probability.  I don't see any linear structure here, so I removed linear algebra.  I see no data here, so I also removed the tag statistics.

Comment: Is the choice between $x^2$ and $x^3$ made according to the coin toss?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think so.

Comment: Your update doesn't change the main idea of both answers, but plz avoid changing the question once you've got an answer in the future.  Related [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25489/290189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the slightly broken English and all, the problem may be reformulated without players:

> Start with $2$ and square or cube it arbitrarily. Show that the number of operations to exceed $n$ is $O(\log\log n)$.

We can take two logs, since $\log$ is strictly increasing, and get the following:

> Start with $\log\log2$ and add $\log2$ or $\log3$ arbitrarily. Show that the number of operations to exceed $\log\log n$ is $O(\log\log n)$.

This is trivially true, since $\log2$ and $\log3$ are constants that are not accounted for explicitly in $O$.

Comment: @MioUnio My answer remains unchanged. The players are completely irrelevant to the problem; regardless of how they square or cube (and that can be treated as a random variable), it is still $O(\log\log n)$ steps.

Comment: @MioUnio The two operations described, squaring and cubing, are both strictly increasing functions. They remain strictly increasing when the logarithms of the numbers before and after those operations are taken. Now the log turns exponentiation into multiplication into addition, the last of which is what we want to show the $O(\log\log n)$ growth.

Answer (score 4):

If we take $\log_2$ of everything, we end up with a simpler game that is equivalent to the original ($\log$ is monotonically increasing, so $x>n$ iff $\log x > \log n$). I will denote $\log_2x$ by $y$ and $\log_2n$ by $m$. When we take the log, squaring becomes doubling, and cubing becomes tripling.

Then this game is equivalent to the following:

Start with $y=1$. The players take turns either doubling or tripling $y$. The game ends when $y >m$.

We can take the log again. When we take the log of a product, that's the sum of the log of the multiplicands, so doubling becomes adding the log of $2$, and tripling becomes adding the log of $3$ (side note: this means that this is a [nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) game, as adding until you reach some number is equivalent to starting at that number and subtracting until you get to zero).  So then the game becomes:

Start with $z=0$. Each turn, players add $\log_22=1$ or $\log_23$ to $z$. The game ends when $z > \log_2m$.

Clearly, this game will end the fastest if each players increases $z$ by $\log_23$ each turn, in which case it will (with rounding) end after $\frac{\log_2m}{\log_23 }= \log_3m = \log_2\log_3n$ turns. The longest it can take is $\log_2\log_2n$. It's not clear that "average" is well defined, but it regardless of how it's defined, it will be between these two numbers. And if we're dealing with Big-O notation, the bases of the logarithms don't matter, so we're left with $\log\log n$

Comment: @MioUnio 1 is the other choice. Acccumulation gave three equivalent games: the "square or cube" game (ending when $x > n$), the "times 2 or times 3" game (ending when $x > log(n)$), and the "add $log(2)$ or $log(3)$" game (ending after $x > log(log(n))$). The base of the logs actually doesn't matter to the argument, but Acccumulation chose base 2, which means your choices in the last game are $+log_2(2)$ and $+log_2(3)$. The first choice happens to be equal to 1.

Answer (score 3):

$x$ is replaced with $x^2$ or $x^3$.
That is, $\log x$ is replaced with $2\log x$ or $3\log x$.
That is, $\log \log x$ is replaced with $\log 2+\log\log x$ or $\log 3+\log\log x$. So for $\log\log x$, we have a simple addition of random vars. In particular, the stopping time is between $\approx\frac{\log\log n-\log\log 2}{\log3}$ and $\approx\frac{\log\log n-\log\log 2}{\log2}$.